How to Retrieve Current API Usage via API Call Instead of Developer Dashboard
I'm looking for a way to retrieve my current API usage via an API call, rather than using the developer/dashboard panel. I can't seem to find any documentation on this. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Tried: I searched the documentation for information on retrieving API usage through an API call.
Expected: I expected to find details on an endpoint or method to get API usage data programmatically.
Result: I couldn't find any documentation or guidance on how to achieve this.
